# Does a spirit need to materialize to use influence?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, spirits

I'm a bit unsure about materializing. A spirit needs to materialize to affect something on the physical level, but Influence power is type "M".  Does the spirit still need to materialize to use this power on a mundane human?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as you're naturally physical. See p301 of core.

> Spirits are naturally astral forms, **much like you’re naturally a physical form**. A spirit exists entirely in astral
> space, with astral attributes equal to its Force. A spirit
> can manifest (p. 314), use astral travel (p. 313), and get
> blocked by mana barriers (p. 315), just like any other
> astral form. Its appearance strongly reflects its type
> and the tradition of the magician who summoned it.
> A hermetic fire spirit might look like a traditional fire
> elemental, while a shaman’s spirit of air might appear
> as an eagle or a butterfly.
> **If a spirit wants to affect anything on the physical
> plane, it has to materialize first** (p. 314). It gets physical
> attributes based on its type (Spirits, p. 303) and appears
> as a solid, physical version of its astral form—it’s relatively solid even if it doesn’t look solid, like a spirit whirlwind
> or a water elemental. The spirit is dual-natured while
> it’s materialized, which means it exists simultaneously on the physical and astral plane, meaning it can see
> objects in both places—and be targeted by both mages
> on the physical plane and astral entities, such as astrally
> projecting mages.

Magical effects need you to be on the same plane as the target. See p282

> Mana spells: When using mana spells, the magician can only
> affect living things with auras or astrally active entities (such as
> spirits or foci) even in the physical world. Mana spells can affect
> targets on either the physical or astral planes, but only if you’re
> on the same plane as your target(s).

A mundane human is naturally a physical form, and so they can't use mana spells on them.